# Excel - Lookup date in matrix and return column heading

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a matrix between Products and Enablers, where the intersection between the two represents a point in time.

| Product list | Enabler 1 | Enabler 2 | Enabler 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | 10-Oct | 11-Oct | 20-Oct |
| Product 2 | 20-Nov | 25-Nov | 01-Dec |
| Product 3 | 10-Oct | 21-Oct | 25-Oct |

I need to turn this into a 'timeline' view so visually there are two ways to see the data, where the dates are across the top and based on the timing in the first table, it returns the corresponding 'Enabler' at the correct date...something like

| Product list | 10-Oct | 11-Oct | 12-Oct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product 1 | Enabler 1 | Enabler 2 |  |
| Product 2 |  |  |  |
| Product 3 | Enabler 1 |  |  |

Does anyone have any ideas how I'd do this? I think it requires an INDEX MATCH array formula as it needs to look across the matrix to find the date in that row, then return what is in the header column...but this isn't my area of expertise and I just can't seem to figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to return this as an array. You could do:

```
=IF( ( Table1[[Enabler 1]:[Enabler 3]] = B7:D7 ) * ( Table1[Product list] = A8:A10),
     Table1[[#Headers],[Enabler 1]:[Enabler 3]],
     "" )
```

where `Table1` is an Excel Table that holds your Product List and Enablers as columns (as shown in your first table); `A8:A10` is the list of products in your second table; and `B7:D7` is the list of dates in your second table shown as column headers.  The formula would be placed in the upper left cell of your second table - in my example, `B8` as shown here:

[image]

The result will spill into the second table.

> If you wanted your second table to be an Excel Table, the approach
> would be different as arrays cannot spill into Excel Tables.

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is close but this only seems to be able to return the 'Enabler' in the same column in which it sits in Table1. In other words, if the date in C3 was changed to 10-Oct, it would not return against Product 2 in the lower table under 10-Oct.

Comment: @wmont101 - ah OK. You might need to add that to the requirements. Show the cases that it must handle and the rules on presentation of the results.